# IF statement, number less than X but greater than Y

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Within my program I have a column(H) specifying hours:

```
(24.2, 23.5, 21.5, 25.0, 28.3, 23.1, 22.5, 17.9, 22.1, 16.2, 24.3, 23.8)
```

this continues for 600 or so more rows.

```
Max hours = 36.88348
Min hours = 16.15569
```

I'm trying to categorise the hours into four different numbers to later use for more accurate data than averages:

```
0 = 16-20,  
1 = 21-25,  
2 = 26-30,  
3 = 31>.
```

So far I have came to this solution:

```
=IF($H4>=31,3,IF($H4<=20,0,IF($H4>=21<=25,1,IF($H4>=26,2))))
```

This works apart from the `21-25($H4>=21<=25,1)`.

If anybody could assist me, I believe it's something basic as my syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Shorter still:

```
=MATCH(H4,{0,21,26,31})-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly shorter:

```
=LOOKUP(H4,{0,21,26,31},{0,1,2,3})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
=IF($H4>=31,3,IF($H4<=20,0,IF(AND($H4>=21,$H4<=25),1,IF($H4>=26,2))))
```

Comment: Thankyou! Didn't know about the AND statement.  This statement was showing FALSE for values between 20-21,25-26, i've edited this statement to:
=IF($H4>=31,3,IF($H4<=20,0,IF(AND($H4>20,$H4<=25),1,IF($H4>25,2))))

This now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just start with the lowest value and work up:

=IF($H4<=20,0,(IF($H4<=25,1,(IF($H4<=30,2,3)))))

Answer (score -1):

The following should work:

```
=IF($H4>=31,3,IF($H4>=26,2,IF($H4>=21,1,IF($H4<21,0))))
```

Comment: This is technically valid Excel syntax but it would not return the desired result. You would have to do this instead: `AND(25>=$H4,$H4>=21)`. Besides, you answered this question 2 years after it was asked!

Comment: True, and you can say same about the user above me who answered back in Feb of this year. Plus I've changed it so that it would give a better result and better Excel syntax.

Comment: Your last `IF` statement is superfluous. `IF($H4>=21,1,IF($H4<21,0))` is equivalent to just this instead: `IF($H4>=21,1,0)`. Also, not sure why you answered this question with this solution when others have already given practically the same solution, and also a more efficient solution was already given years ago, that being `=MATCH(H4,{0,21,26,31})-1`. In general, you should not answer a question if a similar solution already exists, unless you are improving upon all of the current answers to the question. Instead, you should just vote on answers once you get a high enough reputation.